# How to create second array and display numbers that are greater than average number of first array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make second array that gives all numbers using rand function that are greater than average number of first array.

I've created new array and I've tried with if statement to display all numbers greater than average number, and to put those values into a new empty array

```
$arrNums = array();
$arrNewNums = array();
$intSum = 0;
$intTotalNum = 20;

for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++)
{
  $intRand = rand(9, 99);
  $arrNums[] = $intRand;
  $intSum = $intSum + $arrNums[$i];
  $averageNum = $intSum / count($arrNums);

foreach($arrNums as $key => $value)
{
  if($value > $averageNum)
  {
    $arrNewNums[] = rand();
  }
 }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrNums);
echo "<br>";
echo "Average number from array is " . $averageNum;
echo "<br>";
print_r($arrNewNums);
```

I would like to get the output of 20 numbers greater than average number, for example 56.4, but instead of that I'm getting 100 numbers and they are all for example 864165243, 738017258 and so on and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code for your task:

```
$arrNums = array();
$arrNewNums = array();
$intSum = 0;
$intTotalNum = 20;

for($i = 0; $i < $intTotalNum; $i++)
{
  $intRand = rand(9, 99);
  $arrNums[] = $intRand;
  $intSum += $intRand;
}

// count average value AFTER you have all items in array
// $averageNum = array_sum($arrNums) / count($arrNums);
// Without `array_sum`:
$averageNum = $intSum / count($arrNums);

// check values of array AFTER you have all items in array
foreach($arrNums as $value) {
  if($value > $averageNum) {
    // add `$value` to `$arrNewNums`, not some random variable.
    $arrNewNums[] = $value;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrNums);
echo "<br>";
echo "Average number from array is " . $averageNum;
echo "<br>";
print_r($arrNewNums);
```

Comment: Given the previous question. I assume array_sum is not allowed.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I think the OP is asking to get another 20 random numbers greater than the average number.